# Binding values to display:hidden elements

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, razor

If I create a form where some elements have display:hidden on them will the values in those elements get passed to my controller when the user clicks the submit button?

For instance, given a rudimentary form:

```
<form action="dostuff">
  <div style="display:none;">
    <input id="somedata" value="myvalue">
  </div>
</form>
```

Would clicking a submit button here still pass "myvalue" to the controller? If not, then what would be the preferred method of getting said value to the controller from the form?

Comment: The value still will be passed

Comment: A hidden field might be more applicable; `<input id="somedata" type="hidden" value="myvalue" />`

Comment: Values will still get passed, you're only manipulating the visibility property of your elements. It still exists, unless destroyed or you have some sort of function that disallows any kind of programmatic input/passing of values.